# Preserve holes after Contour extraction in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to get a clean vector layer from an elevation raster layer. I'm using ***Raster > Extraction > Contour...*** to get lines from the elevation raster here:

[image]

This tool produces this layer (I kept only one elevation level to keep it simple here):

[image: The lines produced by Contour]

I'm then using ***Vector > Geometry tools > Lines to polygons*** to transform these lines into polygons and it produces this result:

[image]

The problem is: All the parts which are below the main elevation contour are filled. But those should be holes in the main polygon.

[image]

How can I get the polygon with the holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using the Polygonize tool instead of the Contour one. This process is quiet slow though.

First, I use the **Raster Calculator** to isolate each level I want to show. Then I use the **Polygonize (raster to Vector)** and filter the level I want (in my case, 1). Then **Vector geometry tools > Simplify geometry** and finally the **Smooth geometry** tool.

It gives me this nice vector:
[image]